# Show tax rates in percentage instead of total tax value - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my cart beside total amount it shows how much amount of tax included. But I want to show the tax rate only ( percentage value just) instead of the amount. Please help how to do this .
Thanks in advance

[Shows the tax amount but i want to change it to % vlaue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnRpB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be configurable in the options however, i'm pretty sure u would have to show the total tax value according to laws.

WooCommerce > Settings > Tax > Your Tax Rates
there is a display option.

Comment: I set it to per tax rate but still it showing in amount not percentage value

Comment: Clear cache, and try again.

Comment: Thank you for response but still remain same. Hope need changes in the cart-totals.php. But how and what to do I don't know.

Comment: There is no option to set the tax rate